# Why did Watson hallucinate?

Tags: plot-explanation, sherlock

In Sherlock S02E02, The Hounds of Baskerville, Watson gets stuck in a lab and starts hallucinating under the influence of H.O.U.N.D. drug, as Sherlock experiments on him to observe the effects.

However, Sherlock does not have access to the drug (as it is not in the sugar), and has no way that I can see of administering the drug to Watson.

So, how did Watson got the drug in his system?

Comment: This is literally explained in the episode. ["Sherlock surmises that John was poisoned by the leaking pipes in the laboratory, and John realises Sherlock locked him in the labs in order to test his theory."](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Hounds_of_Baskerville)

Comment: @BCdotWEB I find that not entirely convincing, as Sherlock had no way of knowing what was in those pipes at that point

Answer (score 5):

This is explained in the episode as they sit outside the pub at the end.

> As Sherlock and John prepare to leave the next morning, John wonders why he saw the hound in the lab despite not having inhaled the gas from the hollow. **Sherlock surmises that John was poisoned by the leaking pipes in the laboratory, and John realises Sherlock locked him in the labs in order to test his theory.** He also points out Sherlock was wrong for once; he believed the drug was in Henry's sugar and put it in John's coffee.
>
> <sup>[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Hounds_of_Baskerville)</sup>

---

> JOHN: Listen: what happened to me in the lab?
>
> (Sherlock looks at him for a moment, then turns around and reaches for a box of sauce sachets, looking worried about how he’s ever going to explain all this.)
>
> SHERLOCK: D’you want some sauce with that?
>
> JOHN: I mean, I hadn’t been to the Hollow, so how come I heard those things in there? Fear and stimulus, you said.
>
> SHERLOCK (rummaging through the box of sachets): You must have been dosed with it elsewhere, when you went to the lab, maybe. **You saw those pipes – pretty ancient, leaky as a sieve; and they were carrying the gas, so ...** Um, ketchup, was it, or brown ...?
>
> JOHN: Hang on: you thought it was in the sugar.
>
> <sup>[Transcript](http://arianedevere.livejournal.com/28998.html)</sup>

Comment: Nice finding on transcript and plot, but you might wanna add a bit of explanation in your words. :)

Comment: Not sure any more is needed....it's self-explanatory.

Comment: So the drug was in the leaking pipes in the lab? But Sherlock could not have known that at this point, right? Plus, the rest of the lab is very modern, why would they use leaking pipes to transport such a dangerous drug? And he though the drug was in the sugar, so is that just a lucky coincidence?